# Вывод списка новостей

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос: на странице отображается новость из бд news. Нужно, чтобы листинг производился без перезагрузки страницы. Думаю, основную мысль донес...
Хотелось бы увидеть пример или какую документацию, относящуюся к теме. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Я реализовывал разные виды подргузок в своих проектах, посмотрите - может что-то понравится, могу потом пояснить как и что работает. Вот примеры: [zort.ru](http://zort.ru), [darlabel.com](http://darlabel.com), [uniup.ru](http://uniup.ru). Полазьте по сайтам, там много где контент подгружается именно аяксом.

Comment: http://uniup.ru/catalog/ Вот тут очень интересно посмотреть...

Comment: Посмотрите исходный код страницы, точнее - на событие по кликам закладок, что происходит и что подменяется.

Comment: вот, как раз это мне и нужно!!!=)

Comment: Тогда плюсуйте к ответу, помечайте как правильный.

Comment: <div id="catalog-list-container">
<div id="catalog-list-head">
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="420px">Университет:</td>
<td valign="top" width="130px">Город:</td>
<td valign="top">                      <img src="/media/images/star.png" alt="" title="Рейтинг" />               </td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr color="#dfdfdf" size="1px" style="margin-bottom: 13px;"/>
</div>
<!-- Сюда загрузится блок -->
</div>
как я понял в catalog-list-container и подгружаются данные, но не понял где код jQuery под данную схему...

Comment: Как это где, в файле скриптов, [вот он][1]


  [1]: http://uniup.ru/media/scripts.js

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить глянуть эту статью: [динамическая подгрузка данных на страницу](http://www.ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/127-dinamicheskaja_podgruzka_dannyh_na_stranicu.html). Приведен пример подгрузки комментариев на страницу, если немного переделать, то можно добиться и вывода новостей листингом.

Comment: Да, есть что почитать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ну. Вы ж в тегах все правильно написали. К примеру вот так, со страницами. Если вам "бесконечный" листинг в стиле вКонтакте, то нужно отслеживать офсеты объекта и размер экрана, и делать подгрузку и `.append(data)` по факту приближения к концу.

```
function getNews(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'news.php?page=' + page,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#news_div').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

На РНР не забываем делать `$page = intval($_GET['page'])` перед тем, как совать в запрос.
Это если общая идея.

Comment: Над этим поработаю, приму к сведению! Спасибо.